# Saving and restoring object references

Tags: android

I understand that I can save and restore object states via serializable and parcelable, but what if those objects have references to one another? Will their relationship be restored?

For example if my activity has Object A and Object B, and

Object A has a reference to Object B
Object B has a reference to Object A

On restore of Object A, it will recreate an instance of Object B
On restore of Object B, it will recreate an instance of Object A

Therefore the relationship is no longer valid. They no longer reference one another.

How will I keep this relationship, without having to persist and link them up in the SQLite database?

Comment: I believe Parcelables can be nested...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "normal" implementation of the `Parcelable` interface will write all of its fields to the parcel, including other objects (which themselves will write their fields to the parcel). So, in general, when you save and then restore your instance state, all of your object relationships will be in place.

In the special circumstance of circular references between objects you need to save/restore, you can still use `Parcelable` but you will have to customize the writing/reading logic to work around the circular reference.

Consider this minimal activity that defines a `Parcelable` class and tries to save/restore two instances of that class that each reference the other:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_FIRST = "MainActivity.KEY_FIRST";
    private static final String KEY_SECOND = "MainActivity.KEY_SECOND";

    private MyParcelable first;
    private MyParcelable second;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_FIRST, first);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_SECOND, second);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            first = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_FIRST);
            second = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_SECOND);
        }
        else {
            first = new MyParcelable("first name");
            second = new MyParcelable("second name");

            first.companion = second;
            second.companion = first;
        }
    }

    private static class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

        public static final Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR =
                new Creator<MyParcelable>() {

                    @Override
                    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new MyParcelable(in);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new MyParcelable[size];
                    }
                };

        private String name;
        private MyParcelable companion;

        public MyParcelable(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.companion = null;
        }

        private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
            this.name = in.readString();
            this.companion = in.readParcelable(MyParcelable.class.getClassLoader());
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeParcelable(companion, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this activity and rotate your phone, you will find that the two `MyParcelable` objects are succesfully saved and restored, including their references to each other. **However**, if you background the app, you'll get a `StackOverflowError`:

> ```
> 01-09 00:21:35.100 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
> 01-09 00:21:35.101 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
> 01-09 00:21:35.101 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: file=AbstractStringBuilder.java
> 01-09 00:21:35.101 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: class=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
> 01-09 00:21:35.101 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: method=expandCapacity line=130
> 01-09 00:21:35.148 17941 17952 W art     : Suspending all threads took: 23.362ms
> 01-09 00:21:35.164 17941 17941 D Error   : ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
> ```

This makes perfect sense; `outState.putParcelable(KEY_FIRST, first)` will invoke `writeToParcel()`, which will execute `dest.writeParcelable(companion, flags)`, which will invoke `writeToParcel()`, and so on forever.

The solution is to structure our saving and restoring with the same pattern we used when we needed to construct the objects the first time: don't serialize (read: write to the parcel) the "companion" objects, and manually wire them back together after restoring them:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_FIRST = "MainActivity.KEY_FIRST";
    private static final String KEY_SECOND = "MainActivity.KEY_SECOND";

    private MyParcelable first;
    private MyParcelable second;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_FIRST, first);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_SECOND, second);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            first = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_FIRST);
            second = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_SECOND);
        }
        else {
            first = new MyParcelable("first name");
            second = new MyParcelable("second name");
        }

        first.companion = second;
        second.companion = first;
    }

    private static class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

        public static final Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR =
                new Creator<MyParcelable>() {

                    @Override
                    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new MyParcelable(in);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new MyParcelable[size];
                    }
                };

        private String name;
        private MyParcelable companion;

        public MyParcelable(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.companion = null;
        }

        private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
            this.name = in.readString();
            this.companion = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            // do not parcel the companion object
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this solution has the potential to cause problems if you **don't** have a circular reference between two instances of this class. After all, the normal behavior for parceling something would be to write **all** of its structure into the parcel; here we are *intentionally* omitting something in order to solve a special case.